# Insert fixed values using BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to import a TXT file using bcp.

My TXT file is like this:

> ```
> abc|cba
> xyz|zyx
> ```

My Table is like this:

> ```
> Field_1 -> Identity field
> Field_2 -> Varchar(3)
> Field_3 -> Varchar(3)
> Filed_4 -> Varchar(1) In this case I must set with default value 'P'
> Filed_5 -> Varchar(1) In this case I must set with default value 'C'
> ```

My table with values must be:

> ```
> 1,abc,cba,P,C
> 2,xyz,zyx,P,C
> ```

Note-> My TXT file is huge (around 200GB), I can't import into another table to then pass all value to this table (just saying).

@@Version-> SQL Server 2014 (SP2)

Comment: `bcp` can't conjure up data on its own. Alter the table and give it default constraints for the columns you need filled. You can drop these defaults later if they're not wanted for data that isn't bulk inserted. Alternatively, pre-process the file (with PowerShell, for example) so the desired values are appended after every line.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Mostert, I thought there was a way to do that inside BCP config, anyway I'll try your solution, Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate data via BCP, you must depend on SQL Server to do that as Jeroen commented. To add to his comment, the identity value is not a default, you should continue to use the identity property of the column.

For both (identity and default), you must use the -f option to BCP. This the option to include a format file to direct the BCP utility to see and handle the data as stated in the format file.

Using a format file, you can specify which columns in the file are mapped to which columns are in the destination table. To exclude a column, just set its destination value to "0".

The format files and the bcp utility are much larger topics in and of themselves, but to answer your question; yes it is possible and using a format file with modified destination values (set to "0") is the way to do it.

Doing this, you can process the data once. Using powershell to append data is possible, but unnecessary and less efficient. To do this in one action with bcp, you need to use a format file.